# LabeledCheckbox (Checkbox) on the left side of the text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I'm using **CheckboxListTile**, by default the checkbox is to the right of the text. How do I move the ***checkbox to the left*** of the text?

My code:

```
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return LabeledCheckbox(
       label: 'Text of my Checkbox',
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
       value: _isSelected,
       onChanged: (bool newValue) {
         setState(() {
           _isSelected = newValue;
         });
       },
     );
   }
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the checkbox appear on the *left* of the text, you can wrap your widget with a [`Directionality()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) and specify the [`textDirection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality/textDirection.html) to `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl`:

```dart
Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          value: false,
          onChanged: (bool? value) {},
          title: Text("My Text"),
        ),
      )
```

Result:

[image]